# Call to undefined method Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::load()

Tags: php, excel, laravel, laravel-5, maatwebsite-excel

I'm trying to import excel file (.xlsx) using maatwebsite 3.0. How to fix This error

> Call to undefined method Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::load()

My controller

```
public function importsave(Request $request)
{
   if($request->hasFile('excel'))
    {
        $path = $request->file('excel')->getRealPath();
        $data= Excel::load($path, function($reader) {})->get();
        if(!empty($data) && $data->count())
        {
            foreach($data->toArray() as $key=>$value)
            {
                if(!empty($value))
                {
                    Employee::insert($value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Version **3.0** of that package **doesn't handle imports yet**. Release date for this feature is unknown. See this post for more details: https://medium.com/@maatwebsite/laravel-excel-lessons-learned-7fee2812551

I suggest you **switch to version 2.***.

Else you want to continue further
ALL Laravel Excel 2.* methods are deprecated and will not be able to use in 3.0 .

```
   Excel::load() is removed and replaced by Excel::import($yourImport)
    Excel::create() is removed and replaced by Excel::download/Excel::store($yourExport)
    Excel::create()->string('xlsx') is removed an replaced by Excel::raw($yourExport, Excel::XLSX)
```

3.0 provides no convenience methods for styling, you are encouraged to use PhpSpreadsheets native methods.

Comment: @RioAditya could you mark the question as answered?

Comment: Version 3.1 is now available with import functionality https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports

Comment: My whole project is in laravel 6.18 and now I can't install maatwebsite/excel 2.1 or any closer version, please help

Comment: @Swarnadeep did you installed maatwebsite/excel 2.1 and checked?

Answer (score 12):

Hi there in version 3 the load method was remove so switch back to version two like so try using this command,

`composer require "maatwebsite/excel:~2.1.0"`

Comment: its actually "maatwebsite/excel":"~2.1.0"

Comment: Gives an error "- Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.8.18" So it might not be compatible with new versions.

Comment: I have v2.1 maatwebsite/excel and 5.8 laravel do I need to downgrade my laravel version? \

Answer (score 12):

ALL Laravel Excel 2.* methods are deprecated and will not be able to use in 3.0 .

```
Excel::load() is removed and replaced by Excel::import($yourImport)
Excel::create() is removed and replaced by Excel::download/Excel::store($yourExport)
Excel::create()->string('xlsx') is removed an replaced by Excel::raw($yourExport, Excel::XLSX)
```

3.0 provides no convenience methods for styling, you are encouraged to use PhpSpreadsheets native methods.

Comment: this cpuld be the marked answer

Answer (score 11):

Dont panic :) Just do like this

```
Excel::toArray([],$filePath);
```

Just pass an empty array as the first parameter

Comment: works like a charm on package version 3.1 (PHP 8.1, Laravel 9)

Comment: This must be a smartest and perfect answer among all.

Answer (score 9):

`^3.0` versions of `maatwebsite/excel` does not support loads.
Delete the `config/excel.php` file first .

Downgrade the `maatwebsite/excel` version by changing your `composer.json` file from 
 `"maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1"`, to  `"maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1.0"`, and performing 'composer update'.

And if you get an error:

> Undefined class constant 'XLSX' in 2.1 version

this is what you have to do. 
Delete the config/excel.php before downgrading then perform the composer update.

Comment: Doesnt work for laravel 6, its dependency doesnt match

Answer (score 3):

Version 3.0 of Laravel Excel doesn't handle imports.

You could also use an alternative package that works with import such as:

- https://github.com/Cyber-Duck/laravel-excel (Laravel Excel Fork)
- https://github.com/rap2hpoutre/fast-excel (Faster alternative to Laravel Excel)

Both handles import.

You could also switch to version 2, but it means use an old version of a lib.