# Laravel How to upload EXCEL file to database?

Tags: php, excel, laravel, upload

My Laravel version is 5.6.and PHP is 7.
I found some upload sample on the internet, but most of them do not work.
Have anyone can provide a complete example to me?
I found a similar case on the Internet.
[Laravel 5.6  Excel and CSV import export using maatwebsite example](https://hdtuto.com/article/laravel-56-excel-and-csv-import-export-using-maatwebsite-example)

Unfortunately, it doesn't work, too.

Here is my source code.
blade.php

```
<form class="form-upload" method="POST" action="{{url('/excelUpload')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
             <div class="form-group">
                <label for="file">excel upload</label>
                <input type="file" id="file" name="ex_file">
                <p class="help-block">!!!</p>
             </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">cancel</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="upload_f">submit</button>
```

controller.php

```
public function excelUpload(Request $request){

         if($request->hasFile('StudentUploadSample')){
             return "yes i have a file";
         }
         return "nofile";
    }
```

However, the result always show "**nofile**".
I didn't use any "**use**". Should I use something?
The example on the web page does not use any "**use**", too.
In addition, I read some of the websites that the files will be placed under the storage folder, but I can't find my file "StudentUploadSample.xlsx" in the storage folder.

Have anyone can provide a complete example to me or how to solve this problem?

Comment: it will return "nofile" because your input name is different with your request.. your input name is `ex_file`, but you request `StudentUploadSample`. It will return 'nofile'

Comment: Voting for close because it has a typo error. You should use your file name as `StudentUploadSample` or call `hasFile` on `ex_file`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the name of file and use the reference site where you will get the proper code with explanation.

Reference site like: http://www.expertphp.in/article/laravel-5-maatwebsite-import-excel-into-db-and-export-data-into-csv-and-excel

```html
public function importFileIntoDB(Request $request){
    if($request->hasFile('sample_file')){
        $path = $request->file('sample_file')->getRealPath();
        $data = \Excel::load($path)->get();
        if($data->count()){
            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                $arr[] = ['name' => $value->name, 'details' => $value->details];
            }
            if(!empty($arr)){
                \DB::table('products')->insert($arr);
                dd('Insert Record successfully.');
            }
        }
    }
    dd('Request data does not have any files to import.');      
}
```

Comment: yes it work , and thank you.
but... new issue ...... 
the error message show this 
"Call to undefined method Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::load()"

Comment: Please check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49473098/call-to-undefined-method-maatwebsite-excel-excelload

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You use the wrong name of the file in your controller:

```
if($request->hasFile('ex_file')){
     return "yes i have a file";
  }
```

So fix that, and try to check.

Comment: yes it work , and thank you.
but... new issue ...... 
the error message show this 
"Call to undefined method Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::load()"
do you kbow

Answer (score 0):

replace `<input type="file" id="file" name="ex_file">` with `<input type="file" id="file" name="StudentUploadSample">`

and you are done.

Comment: yes it work , and thank you.
but... new issue ...... 
the error message show this 
"Call to undefined method Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::load()"
do you kbow

Answer (score 0):

you can use laravel excel.

address：https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel

/**
 * my Controller code
 *
 */

$updateFile = $request->file('update_file');

$fileSize = (int) filesize($updateFile);

$fileExtension = $updateFile->getClientOriginalExtension();

$filePath = $updateFile->getRealPath();

$excelData = Excel::load($filePath)->get()->toArray();

or you can use: https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/

Comment: ah... i am using it