# Maatwebsite Laravel Excel Undefined Index error when Importing

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, csv, import

I want to import a csv file containing large data but If i want to import It says `undefined index` even if I already configured the headers already in my controller. And I want to break down the `address` column into parts as you can see i got 5 columns named `unitname`, `block`,`street`,`level`,`stack`. My addres column example is like this `261 River Valley Road  #09-21` which is `261` is `block`, `River Valley` is `street`, `#09` is `level`, `21` is `stack` and  unitname is `#09-21` . `transtype` is static value.  Can someone know how could I fix this? Thanks

error I got `Undefined index: Project Name`

CSV sample here https://gofile.io/?c=XLUclQ

My controller

```
public function import(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->hasFile('template')){
            $path = $request->file('template')->getRealPath();
            $data = \Excel::load($path)->get();
            if($data->count() > 0){
                $rows = $data->toArray();
                // dd($rows);
                foreach ($rows as $row) {
                    $inserts[]=[
                        'transtype' => 'RESI',
                        'project_name' => $row['Project Name'],
                        'unitname' => $row['Address'],
                        'block' => $row['Address'],
                        'street' => $row['Address'],
                        'level' => $row['Address'],
                        'stack' => $row['Address'],
                        'no_of_units' => $row['No. of Units'],
                        'area' => $row['Area (sqm)'],
                        'type_of_area' => $row['Type of Area'],
                        'transacted_price' => $row['Transacted Price ($)'],
                        'nettprice' => $row['Nett Price($)'],
                        'unitprice_psm' => $row['Unit Price ($ psm)'],
                        'unitprice_psf' => $row['Unit Price ($ psf)'],
                        'sale_date' => $row['Sale Date'],
                        'contract_date' => $row['Sale Date'],
                        'property_type' => $row['Property Type'],
                        'tenture' => $row['Tenure'],
                        'completion_date' => $row['Completion Date'],
                        'type_of_sale' => $row['Type of Sale'],
                        'purchaser_address_indicator' => $row['Purchaser Address Indicator'],
                        'postal_district' => $row['Postal District'],
                        'postal_sector' => $row['Postal Sector'],
                        'postal_code' => $row['Postal Code'],
                        'planning_region' => $row['Planning Region'],
                        'planning_area' => $row['Planning Area'],
                    ];
                }

            }

            if(empty($inserts)){
                dd('Request data does not have any files to import.');  
            }
            else {
                \DB::table('xp_pn_ura_transactions')->insert($inserts);
                dd('record inserted');  
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: When you get this error? when form submitted or when a form is loading

Comment: when i submit my form, it goes to `/imports'` url with a blank page but if i enter again the url, the error appears and the data is not inserted

Comment: what do you think is wrong with my code sir? @YasinPatel

Comment: *but if i enter again the url, the error appears* - in this case it is not a POST request.

Comment: so there is no error in your url , the blank page  is because you have redirected to view or link in your controller

Comment: i changed the `sample_file` to `template` in my controller it seems correct but I got new error which is `Call to undefined method Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::load()`

Comment: @user001232 have you model for xp_pn_ura_transactions table?

Comment: yes. but my model called `Records'

Comment: i forgot to put `protected $table`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49473098/call-to-undefined-method-maatwebsite-excel-excelload :

Comment: yes i already changed versions. Ill just wait for the output

Comment: can someone post their answers?  so that I can mark as correct or upvote for helping me

Comment: are you uploading file using form?

Comment: yes. I already solved the error. Im encountering new error now, Can u help me in chat ?@PrashantDeshmukh.....

Comment: You can post it here so others can also contribute.

Comment: I cannot post because I recently posted this question, Stackoverflow lets me post questions every 90 min

Comment: @user001232, edit this question

Comment: okay sir thanks for helping me i owe you a lot

Comment: here is example for import  : https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-57-import-export-excel-to-database-exampleexample.html

Comment: I already edited my question sirs. Thanks a lot really

Comment: Can i use str split in importing csv's?