# Load Data Of Xlsx File In Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am Trying To Open A Xlsx File By Using Maatwebsite Excel But its showing error

> "Call to undefined method Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::load()"

This is my Code

```
$dir=storage_path('navs/');
        $a = scandir($dir);

        for($i=0;$i<count($a);$i++)
        {
            if($a[$i]!='.' && $a[$i]!='..')
            {

                $file = Excel::load('storage/navs/' . $a[$i])->first()->keys();
                print_r($file);
            }
        }
```

Please Help me out

Comment: What version of `maatwebsite/excel` are you using?

Comment: maatwebsite/excel 3.1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call to undefined method Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::load()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49473098/call-to-undefined-method-maatwebsite-excel-excelload)

Comment: Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content this error is popping up